# ExpandableList crash when i select a group

Tags: java, android, sqlite, expandablelistadapter

hi I create an app that save my sales Invoice in sqlite sad show it again  you can see example data in picture.

[image]

[image]

now i want add data to a expanded list adapter
each row in HFO is a group in my list view.
and each DFO that Hid = id is child for HFO.
i add group data but when i want open a group my app crashed

please help my tank you.

dfo_listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxchilditem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvchilditem"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDfo_Rid_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxchilditem"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDfo_Qty_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvDfo_Rid_child"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvDfo_Rid_child"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDfo_Rid_child"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDfo_Kprice_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDfo_Qty_child"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDfo_Sumprice_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

hfo_listiem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#cb9216" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivgroup"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHfo_Gcode_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivgroup"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHfo_Ttem_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvHfo_Gcode_group"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHfo_SumKprice_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvHfo_Ttem_group"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHfo_tv4_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvHfo_SumKprice_group"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="show data" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DFoStruct.java

```
      int DFo_HID;  
      int Dfo_RID;  
      String   Dfo_KCode;
      Double Dfo_KQty1;
      Double  Dfo_KQty2; 
      Double Dfo_RUnit1_2;
      String   Dfo_KPrice;
      String Dfo_KTakh;
      String Dfo_KTax;
      String Dfo_SumPrice;
      String Dfo_KDesc;
      Boolean State;
```

HFoStruct.java

```
int HFoID;
int HFoNu;
String FoKind;
String HFo_GCode;
int HFoItem;
String HFoDesc;
String HFoTarikh;
String HFoUn_Takh;
String HFoK_Takh;
String HFoTot_Takh;
String HFoTot_Tax;
String HFoSum_KPrice;
String HFoTot_Price;
String IsSend;
String SendDate;
Boolean state;
```

my list activity:

```
    public class Listsefaresh_Activity extends ExpandableListActivity {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox2";
        private ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter;

        Button b;
        ArrayList<String> groupNames;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors;
        ArrayList<Color> color;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<HFoStruct>> hFoStructs;
        ArrayList<HFoStruct> hFoStruct;
    //  List<GuyStruct> hfolist;
        List<HFoStruct> hfolist;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<DFoStruct>> dFoStructs;
        ArrayList<DFoStruct> dFoStruct;
        List<DFoStruct> dfolist;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.factor_list);

            try {
                hFoStructs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HFoStruct>>();
                hFoStruct = new ArrayList<HFoStruct>(); 
                dFoStructs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<DFoStruct>>();
                dFoStruct = new ArrayList<DFoStruct>();

                G.HFoList.addAll(G.dbHelper.getAllHfo());
                hfolist = G.HFoList;

                G.DFoList.addAll(G.dbHelper.getAllDfo());
                dfolist = G.DFoList;

                for (int i = 0; i < hfolist.size(); i++) {
                    hFoStruct.add(hfolist.get(i));
                    Toast.makeText(Listsefaresh_Activity.this, String.valueOf(hFoStruct.get(i).getHFo_GCode()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (int j = 0; j < dfolist.size(); j++) {
                        if (dfolist.get(j).getDFo_HID() == hfolist.get(i).getHFoID()) {
                            dFoStruct.add(dfolist.get(j));
                            Toast.makeText(Listsefaresh_Activity.this, String.valueOf(dFoStruct.get(j).getDfo_KPrice()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                hFoStructs.add(hFoStruct);
                dFoStructs.add(dFoStruct);
    //      Toast.makeText(Listsefaresh_Activity.this, String.valueOf(dfolist.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.size(); i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < colors.get(i).size(); j++) {
                                if (colors.get(i).get(j).state == true) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            Listsefaresh_Activity.this,
                                            String.valueOf(groupNames.get(i)) + " "
                                                    + String.valueOf(j + 1),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

    //  setdata();


                expListAdapter = new Hfo_Dfo_Adabter(this, hfolist, dfolist, hFoStructs, dFoStructs);
                setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onContentChanged() {
            super.onContentChanged();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onContentChanged");
        }

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    }
}
```

Hfo_Dfo_Adabter.java

```
package my_adabters;

import ir.nanohesab.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Struct.DFoStruct;
import Struct.HFoStruct;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Hfo_Dfo_Adabter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<HFoStruct> hfolist = null;
    private List<DFoStruct> dfolist = null;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<HFoStruct>> hFoStructs = null;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<DFoStruct>> dFoStructs = null;

    /*
     * private List<HFoStruct> HFolist = null; private List<DFoStruct> DFolist =
     * null;
     */
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Hfo_Dfo_Adabter(Context context, List<HFoStruct> hfolist,
            List<DFoStruct> dfolist,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<HFoStruct>> hFoStructs,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<DFoStruct>> dFoStructs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.hfolist = hfolist;
        this.dfolist = dfolist;
        this.hFoStructs = hFoStructs;
        this.dFoStructs = dFoStructs;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        try {
            return dFoStructs.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        try {
            return (long) (groupPosition * 1024 + childPosition);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (Long) null; 
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = null;  

            try {

            if (convertView != null)
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dfo_listitem, parent, false);
            DFoStruct d = (DFoStruct) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            TextView tvDfo_Rid_child = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDfo_Rid_child);
            TextView tvDfo_Qty_child = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDfo_Qty_child);
            TextView tvDfo_Kprice_child = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDfo_Kprice_child);
            TextView tvDfo_Sumprice_child = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDfo_Sumprice_child);

            if (tvDfo_Rid_child != null)
                tvDfo_Rid_child.setText(String.valueOf(d.getDfo_RID()));
            if (tvDfo_Qty_child != null)
                tvDfo_Qty_child.setText(String.valueOf(d.getDfo_KQty1()));

            if (tvDfo_Kprice_child != null)
                tvDfo_Kprice_child.setText(String.valueOf(d.getDfo_KPrice()));
            if (tvDfo_Sumprice_child != null)
                tvDfo_Sumprice_child.setText(String.valueOf(d.getDfo_SumPrice()));

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxchilditem);

            cb.setChecked(d.getState());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
            return v;

    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return dFoStructs.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return hfolist.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return hfolist.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long) (groupPosition * 1024); // To be consistent with
                                                // getChildId
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        try {

            if (convertView != null)
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hfo_listitem, parent, false);

            HFoStruct h = hfolist.get(groupPosition);

            TextView tvHfo_Gcode_group = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvHfo_Gcode_group);
            TextView tvHfo_Ttem_group = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvHfo_Ttem_group);
            TextView tvHfo_SumKprice_group = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvHfo_SumKprice_group);
            TextView tvHfo_tv4_group = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvHfo_tv4_group);

            if (tvHfo_Gcode_group != null)
                tvHfo_Gcode_group.setText(String.valueOf(h.getHFo_GCode()));

            if (tvHfo_Ttem_group != null)
                tvHfo_Ttem_group.setText(String.valueOf(h.getHFoItem()));

            if (tvHfo_SumKprice_group != null)
                tvHfo_SumKprice_group.setText(String.valueOf(h.getHFoSum_KPrice()));

            if (tvHfo_tv4_group != null)
                tvHfo_tv4_group.setText("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;

    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    }

    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    }

}


01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): Process: ir.nanohesab, PID: 1337
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at my_adabters.Hfo_Dfo_Adabter.getChildrenCount(Hfo_Dfo_Adabter.java:102)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:563)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:688)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:691)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-06 20:50:05.324: E/InputDispatcher(466): channel '4aa23a4c ir.nanohesab/ir.nanohesab.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    01-06 20:50:05.324: E/InputDispatcher(466): channel '4aa38234 ir.nanohesab/new_job.Listsefaresh_Activity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    01-06 20:50:05.324: E/InputDispatcher(466): channel '4aa38dec Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

i want show data to expended list and when i click button i get all checked item.

Comment: please show your logcat

Comment: @StefanBeike i send it

Comment: Please, edit your question, copy the logcat, and then post and format the text..

Comment: Le me rephrase it. Please, instead of images, copy the Logcat, then paste it on the question. Then format the logcat so that it can be read by other users. The failure you have is IndexOutOfBounds, you are accessing the `array[1]` of an array with size 1, so, just the `array[0]` exists.

Comment: @Bonatti wher is my problem??

Comment: From the Logcat image that you had, I was able to read the exception throw. This exceptions meant that you were trying to use the an index in an array that was out of bounds. Since your code is hard to read, and full of images, I gave up... Edit your question again, to empasize the Logcat, and pay extra focus on this line: `01-06 20:50:03.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this method:

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return dFoStructs.get(groupPosition).size();
}
```

`dFoStructs` has exactly one element.
If you try to get the value with index 1 it must leads to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the `Array` starts at position `0`.

if the counting of `groupPosition` starts at position 1, you have to take care that you decrease the index like this:

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return dFoStructs.get(groupPosition-1).size();
}
```